# Collapsing The Divs Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

following is My Code for Collapsing div on Click using JavaScript It is Working Fine But i Want to Precise the onClick Function in Script Any Suggestion will Highly appreciated.Thnx In Advanced.

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
    body,
    button {
      font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    }

    h2 {
      font-weight: "bold";
    }

    .chevron-up {
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      display: inline-block;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
    }

    .chevron-down {
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      display: inline-block;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
    }

    .collapsible {
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 13px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
    }


    .content {
      padding: 0 18px;
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
      font-size: 11px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    }

    .content a {
      color: #f7941d;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>How can we help?</h2>


  <button class="collapsible">
    How to Redeem a Voucher
    <span class="chevron-down" />
  </button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Making Redemption through App is easy, Here’s how it goes:
    </p>
    <ol>
      <li>Tap on the offer you want to redeem.</li>
      <li>Ask the merchant to enter their PIN.</li>
      <li>
        You’ll get the smiley screen showing your estimated savings amount.
      </li>
      <li>Make sure to activate Bogo App first, <a href="www.google.com">Haven’t purchased it yet?</a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <button class="collapsible">
    How to Activate my account
    <span class="chevron-down" />
  </button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
      magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat.
    </p>
  </div>
  <button class="collapsible">
    I forgot my Password
    <span class="chevron-down" />
  </button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
      magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat.
    </p>
  </div>

  <script>
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
      coll[i].onclick = function () {
        if (this.classList.contains('active')) {
          this.classList.remove('active');
          this.firstElementChild.classList.remove("chevron-up")
          this.firstElementChild.classList.add("chevron-down")
          this.style.maxHeight = null;
          this.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;

        } else {
          for (let j = 0; j < coll.length; j++) {
            coll[j].classList.remove('active');
            coll[j].style.maxHeight = null;
            coll[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
            coll[j].firstElementChild.classList.remove("chevron-up")
            coll[j].firstElementChild.classList.add("chevron-down")
          }
          this.classList.add("active");
          this.firstElementChild.classList.remove("chevron-down")
          this.firstElementChild.classList.add("chevron-up")
          var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + 'px'
        }

      }
    }


  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Avoid repeating in the CSS. The rules for the classes `chevron-up` and `chevron-down` are identical except for the image. Have a separate rule für the common properties like this:

```
.chevron-up, .chevron-down {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.chevron-up {
  background-image: url(...);
}

.chevron-down {
  background-image: url(...);
}
```

(NB, unless it's just for this example, don't use `data:` URLs. They bloat the CSS.)

Or, if you have more similar icons, use a separate class:

```
.icon {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.chevron-up {
  background-image: url(...);
}

.chevron-down {
  background-image: url(...);
}
```

with

```
<span class="icon chevron-up"></span>
```

BTW, it's invalid HTML to use self-closing tags (`<span />`) on elements such as `span`. They must be written with explicit start and end tags.

You should consider removing these icon elements anyway. HTML should contain content and empty elements like that aren't content. Instead use the CSS pseudo-element `::after`:

```
.collapsible::after {
  content: "";
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(...); // chevron-down icon
}

.collapsible.active::after {
  background-image: url(...); // chevron-up icon
}
```

This way you also don't need to switch the `chevron-up`/`chevron-down` classes in the JavaScript.

In JavaScript don't use the `on...` event properties. The `on...` properties only allow a single event handler, that can be overwritten by a different script. Instead us `addEventListener`.